# Inserting large object into SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to insert a large object into a single data row. I encounter a timeout when the size of the object becomes to large.

One of the properties in the object is a `byte[]`. The object only has a few properties, the rest of which are `int`.

The destination table has a column of type `varbinary(max)` to hold the `byte[]` property. The insert is done via a stored procedure, wrapped in a transaction, and uses the `ROWLOCK` hint for the insert (this table only exists locally at the moment, so locking shouldn't be the issue at this point.)

When the `byte[]` contains up to about 200MB of data, the insert works fine. After that, it gets really ugly and starts to timeout (memory is probably not an issue on my machine).

I have changed the settings on the database to autoexpand by 500MB and set the recovery mode to simple. This transaction should be really fast but there seems to be a bottleneck somewhere.

Any ideas for database changes or alternative methods for writing large-ish objects to `varbinary` columns? Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried setting an appropriate [timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value for the connection?

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz - The timeout is set to 45 seconds.

Comment: And you increase the timeout value and command still fails to execute?

Comment: Just for testing, I set the timeout to 5 minutes. Still timed out.

Comment: 200MB is too much data to hold it in SQL. With right timeouts it may works but logically it looks like bad idea. Why not store it in file and put filename in database? BTW, are you using FILESTREAM varbinary?

Comment: No. I haven't been using Varbinary(max) FILESTREAM. Just Varbinary(max).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL databases aren't really optimized to store large amounts of binary data. I would recommend storing the `byte[]` contents in a form of storage that works well with large documents. For example:

- a file on a hard disk
- a cloud-based blob storage solution like AWS

Then have your table in SQL Server store a reference (e.g. file path or AWS ID) to that document.

Comment: Yes indeed, databases are no replacement for file systems.

Comment: It would be nice if you would add more explanation to the OP as to *why* and specifically how he should *access* it later.

Comment: I likely will move toward saving and indexing this data within a fileshare. I still would like to complete this POC as I think it's still possible. VARBINARY(MAX) can hold 2^31-1 bytes/2+ GB. Where could the bottleneck be?

Comment: @neonScarecrow: Relational databases use internal storage mechanisms that are optimized for storing and querying smallish pieces of related, structured data (e.g. numbers, strings, and dates). They are typically very inefficient at storing and retrieving large amounts of binary data. Just because the VARBINARY(MAX) type is capable of storing this data, that doesn't mean it can do so quickly, or without impacting performance. If you want to store data of this size in SQL Server anyway, it may be better to store this data as a BLOB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx